# Adding an outlet in an Ember.ListView

Tags: listview, ember.js

I am creating an application where the look and feel is similar to Google Images Search: https://www.google.ca/search?q=vancouver&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi.

I successfully created the list of images using `Ember.ListView` (http://emberjs.com/list-view/). I want to have a List/Details interface where the Details will be displayed in a popover (like in Google: try clicking on an image).

So a template like:

```
{{view Ember.ListView contentBinding="model"}}{{outlet}}
```

would works. I can see the details popover when I transition to the details. However, the Details outlet should be inserted in the scrollable container and not outside the `Ember.ListView`. My first idea was to extend the `Ember.ListView` in order to push a view that will act as an `outlet` in the `Ember.ListView`:

```
App.ListView = Ember.ListView.extend({
  itemViewClass: App.ListItemView,
  childViewsWillSync: function() {
    this.removeObject(this.get(this, 'anOutletView'));

    this._super();
  },
  childViewsDidSync: function() {
    var anOutletView = this.get(this, 'anOutletView');

    this._super();

    if (!anOutletView) {
        anOutletView =  App.AnOutletView.create();
        this.set('anOutletView', anOutletView );
    }

    this.pushObject(anOutletView );
  }
});

App.AnOutletView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet}}')
});
```

My template is now:

```
{{view App.ListView contentBinding="model"}}
```

I can see the instance of `App.AnOutletView` in the DOM, however nothing is getting rendered inside. I would be surprise if this would have been working!

Any idea how I can add an outlet whithin an `Ember.ListView`? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do the template for the list item like this?

```
<!-- Not expanded -->
{{#if isExpanded}}
    <!-- Expanded -->
{{/if}}
```